# Venom Bot - Problem With SendFiles, "Error to processFiles"

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the code below I'm trying to send a PDF, it's giving me the following error
node version: 20.9.0
venom-bot version: 5.0.22

```
app.post('/send-pdf',[
 body('number').notEmpty(),
 ], async (req, res) => {
 const errors = validationResult(req).formatWith(({
 msg
 }) => {
 return msg
 })
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(422).json({
            status: false,
            message: errors.mapped()
        });
    }
    
    const number = req.body.number;
    const path ='./curso.pdf'
    const fileName = 'Curso';
    const description = 'curso auto';

    //client.sendText(number,message);
    client.sendFile(number,path,fileName,description).then(response => {
        res.status(200).json({
            status: true,
            message: 'Mensagem enviada',
            response: response
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            status: false,
            message: 'Mensagem não enviada',
            response: err.text
        });
    });
    //res.send('Mensagem enviada');
})  


ERRO:

"me": {
    "id": {
        "server": "c.us",
        "user": "557788890834",
        "_serialized": "557788890834@c.us"
    },
    "displayName": null,
    "verifiedName": null,
    "searchName": null,
    "pushname": "Igor",
    "notifyName": null,
    "isBusiness": null,
    "formattedUser": null,
    "tag": "1697060691",
    "eurl": "https://pps.whatsapp.net/v/t61.24694-                                             24/384857814_1377715469846899_8485044292930854182_n.jpg?ccb=11-4&oh=01_AdT3wwl9xqvMsS_lDs-      wuzxjh0uuIY4Bndu0dXyrhCBLyA&oe=65651B11&_nc_sid=e6ed6c&_nc_cat=105",
    "previewEurl": "https://pps.whatsapp.net/v/t61.24694-24/384857814_1377715469846899_8485044292930854182_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s96x96&ccb=11-4&oh=01_AdQ2wlC95WTnG1oztzgpqA_3UuuUCFtqLN8RT8h21QuLWQ&oe=65651B11&_nc_sid=e6ed6c&_nc_cat=105",
    "fullDirectPath": "/v/t61.24694-24/384857814_1377715469846899_8485044292930854182_n.jpg?ccb=11-4&oh=01_AdT3wwl9xqvMsS_lDs-wuzxjh0uuIY4Bndu0dXyrhCBLyA&oe=65651B11&_nc_sid=e6ed6c&_nc_cat=105",
    "previewDirectPath": "/v/t61.24694-24/384857814_1377715469846899_8485044292930854182_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s96x96&ccb=11-4&oh=01_AdQ2wlC95WTnG1oztzgpqA_3UuuUCFtqLN8RT8h21QuLWQ&oe=65651B11&_nc_sid=e6ed6c&_nc_cat=105",
    "filehash": "M6RwDPMQ9u1O5XnuoQI2MKNgSYdHqdTkTYfpxH1Zilg=",
    "stale": false,
    "eurlStale": false,
    "timestamp": 1700268717737,
    "hostRetryCount": 0,
    "lastHostUsed": {
        "hostname": "media-for1-1.cdn.whatsapp.net",
        "ips": [
            {
                "ip4": "157.240.216.60",
                "ip6": "2a03:2880:f259:c8:face:b00c:0:167"
            }
        ],
        "type": "primary",
        "class": "pop",
        "downloadBuckets": [
            0
        ],
        "_supportedDownloadTypes": {},
        "_supportedUploadTypes": {},
        "fallback": {
            "hostname": "media-gig4-2.cdn.whatsapp.net",
            "ips": [
                {
                    "ip4": "31.13.91.60",
                    "ip6": "2a03:2880:f27c:1cd:face:b00c:0:167"
                }
            ],
            "type": "fallback",
            "class": "pop",
            "downloadBuckets": [
                0
            ],
            "_supportedDownloadTypes": {},
            "_supportedUploadTypes": {},
            "fallback": null
        },
        "selectedBucket": 102
    }
},
"to": {
    "server": "c.us",
    "user": "557781107704",
    "_serialized": "5577987625435@c.us"
},
"erro": true,
"text": "Error to processFiles",
"status": 404
```

}
}

Error to processFiles, it's a pdf it's working, the file is in this path 'D:portifa/venom/curso.pdf', but for some reason it's not being able to process, and I couldn't find a possible solution anywhere(I've tried to insert the path, in different ways), I was able to send buttons and messages on other routes, but for some reason this file and no other are being processed

Has anyone ever had this problem?

I tried to send a PDF, following the steps in the reference documentation, but for some reason it cannot be processed, I tried with other files and the result was the same.

Comment: I got same error, and solving it, have you got any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with NPM which was used I guess.

I got solutions like this,

It's not the best way, but I do it to fix it...
if you need more details then let me know, its issue is in npm (node_modules)

make one file "fix-venom.js".

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs');

const path = './node_modules/venom-bot/dist/lib/wapi/wapi.js'

let toFix = readFileSync(path);


toFix = toFix.toString().replace(
    `return await n.processAttachments("0.4.613"===Debug.VERSION?t:t.map((e=>({file:e}))),e,1),n}`,
    `return await n.processAttachments("0.4.613"===Debug.VERSION?t:t.map((e=>({file:e}))),e,e),n}`
)

writeFileSync(path, toFix)
```

and before starting the project, I ran that script.

like

```
{
......
"prestart": "node fix-venom.js"
}
```

For more information, you can visit this link:
https://github.com/orkestral/venom/issues/2485

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you so much, you saved my life!